# How to add more than one dummy-variable in TWFE?

Tags: r, output, linear-regression, dummy-variable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spi0G.png)I designed a twfe model with a dummy variable in order to do a diff in diff. In order to introduce new independent variables, I would need to introduce two more dummies (nord/south and sea/lake municipality). If I add them in the code and then summarize the results, I do not see the estimates of these coefficients.

Is it not possible to introduce more than one dummy? With other variables like number of demographics i do not have any problem.

Below the code:

```
## read the data
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("~/link")

## load packages
library(dplyr)      ## for wrangling the data
library(plm)        ## for the regression
library(lmtest)     ## for robust standard errors

## coerce MUNICIPALITY and YEAR variables to factor
data <- data %>%
  mutate_at(c("MUNICIPALITY", "YEAR"), as.factor)

## run the regression
model_beds <- plm(formula = beds ~ DID + balneare, data = data, effect = "twoways",
                  model = "within", index = c("MUNICIPALITY", "YEAR"))

## summarize the results of the regression
summary(model_beds)
```

And the output=

```
Call:
plm(formula = hotelbeds ~ DID + sea, data = data, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within", index = c("MUNICIPALITY", "YEAR"))

Balanced Panel: n = 78, T = 18, N = 1404

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-1229.853   -64.005   -11.272    71.209  1728.606 

Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
DID   55.471     23.342  2.3765  0.01762 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    73147000
Residual Sum of Squares: 72833000
R-Squared:      0.0042991
Adj. R-Squared: -0.068019
F-statistic: 5.64753 on 1 and 1308 DF, p-value: 0.017623
```

How can I fix this problem and introduce more than one dummy variable?

The data is structured like that:

Comment: if you are looking for an estimate for `balneare` - does this vary within `MUNICIPALITY` ?

Comment: Yes, it is the variabile if the municipality is near the sea ( 1) or near the lake (0). But my DID variable does as well (1 for treated). I know very few about the model, sorry! I was asked to add it, and I do not know why I do not get an estimate of it. I use It for an university project, but never used R before.

Comment: can you post the data? My guess is that because a municipality is either near the sea or not, the parameter is not identifiable with municipality fixed effects, in which case - plm drops it. what does this look like: data %>% group_by(MUNICIPALITY) %>% summarise(within_sd = sd(balneare))

Comment: I do not know how to load the data. I tried to add a picture of the dataset. I tried also to use your code, but it still drops the variable.

Comment: the code was just to show the within municipality variance, from the picture you posted, which does not show every municipality, balneare does not vary within municipality. If it does not vary within municipality, it isnt identifiable in your model, which includes municipality fixed effects, so it isnt displayed.